# display info of event target is ko

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, vuejs2, vuejs3

I have a button with id & name that I wanted to display their value but in my code nothing is displayed.
what is wrong with it ?

```
  <v-btn id="mytest" name="test" @click="addNewEntry">{{'add '}}</v-btn>


  methods: {
    addNewEntry() {
        document.getElementById("mytest").addEventListener('click', (event) => {        
        console.log('id value ' , event.target.id);
        console.log('name value ' , event.target.name)
      });
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ref` and call `this.$refs` to get the attribute of the button.

## For vuetify 2

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    methods: {
      addNewEntry() {
        console.log('id value', this.$refs.myBTN['$attrs'].id)
        console.log('name value', this.$refs.myBTN['$attrs'].name)
      },
    },
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.7.1/dist/vuetify.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.7.1/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>



<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-btn 
           ref="myBTN"
           id="mytest" 
           name="test" 
           @click="addNewEntry()"
    >
      Add 
    </v-btn>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

## For vuetify 3

Here's a [Demo.](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNqVUMFuAiEU/JUXYqImyibak9k2tUmvnnpzPVB4VlIWCDy3GrP/XoR2W4+e3huYGWbYXlgMslp7z7sjshWrCVtvBOFTYwFqpTuQRsT42DDCE80lWsLQsHydCN38nSwE3CdCe3552zQMtMqAMFJCVrSY1Rk9S6PlZ8JCqQ1+vVoK58l08ANYK/VjXWXvkqNKQdJWV//iJRhl0J4yBU/eBQKFe3E0BJdi0iIdnIqrXwxw8+7fMYB0NjqD3LiPCR105KPUKvJcajsejXdcEIXItZreL7p+wiDrZ2Urs7/WGoqwfsaWfMkfWJmLBdt9A6cahK4=)

Comment: yet what is `['$'].attrs` what does **$** & attrs means ? or to what they refer ?

Comment: it's a *name* to pinpoint the [attribute](https://i.imgur.com/TkCIxfK.png) of your button.

Comment: I tried to make a test on **p** element `<p ref="pa" name="po">hello</p>`    `console.log(this.$refs.pa['$'].attrs.name)` but I got **Cannot read properties of undefined**

Comment: **p** is different *tag* use ```console.log(this.$refs.pa['__vnode'].props.name)```

Answer (score 1):

You already have an event listener attached to your method via `@click="addNewEntry"` so just do:

```
  methods: {
    addNewEntry(event) {
      console.log('id value ' , event.target.id);
      console.log('name value ' , event.target.name)
    },
  }
```

Comment: can you add a runnable example ? in my case `event.target.id` displays 1 instead of **"mytest"** and `event.target.name` returns **undefined** instead of **"test"**

Comment: the solution is to use `event.currentTarget.id` & `event.currentTarget.name` instead of `event.target.id` & `event.target.name`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading a bit more about [vue v-model](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html) and [event handling in vue](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html)

But in short, when you add `@click='methodName'`, that already adds an event listener so it is not needed to add `document.getElementById("mytest").addEventListener(...)` inside your method.

One more thing, `{{'add '}}`: you should only put variables inside the {{}}. Since 'add' is a constant string here, then you can write this instead: 'add ' {{ someVariable }}

With that said, an answer to your question will use some of the points mentioned above:
add a variables in your data to store the values for id and name. And use v-model to bind that variable with the input where the value is entered.

```
data () {
 return {
  name: ''
 }
},
methods: {
 addNewEntry() {
   console.log('name value ' , this.name)
 }
```

}

And in your html input bind the relevant values

```
<input type="text" v-model="name">
<v-btn id="mytest" name="test" @click="addNewEntry">add {{ name }}</v-btn>
```